# MySQL : delete all records based on an id and other colums content

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I got the following table

```
+----+---------+---------+
| id |  val1   |  val2   |
+----+---------+---------+
|  1 |  aaaa   |  bbbb   |
|  2 |  cccc   |  dddd   |
|  3 |  aaaa   |  eeee   |
|  4 |  ffff   |  bbbb   |
|  5 |  aaaa   |  bbbb   |
+----+---------+---------+
```

I have identified I need to delete the record with id = 1

But I want also delete all the records having same val1 and val2 as id 1.

In this case, id 5 should also me removed.

I have tried that with no luck

```
SELECT id FROM table t1
INNER JOIN table t2
ON t1.val1 = t2.val1
AND t1.val2 = t2.val2
AND t1.id = 1
```

Comment: haha :) corrected thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use a subquery

```
delete t
from table t
inner join  (
  select val1, val2
  from table 
  where id = 1 
) s on s.val1 = t.val1 
      and s.val2 = t.val2
```

Comment: `AND t1.id = 1` ... t2.id

Comment: @Akina  . if the OP want delete the record  with the same val1, val2 for id = 1  ..the query should be right

Comment: OP accepts, of course, but nevertheless investigate [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7fb9c7b4f468ebec2949224facc0a818). No reason for a records `id=5` to be deleted from `t1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a self join and the condition `id = 1` in the `WHERE` clause:

```
delete t1  
from tablename t1 inner join tablename t2
on t1.val1 = t2.val1 and t1.val2 = t2.val2
where t2.id = 1;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xoXFH9uzdjZb1a7P9rH5Hc/0).
Results:

```
| id  | val1 | val2 |
| --- | ---- | ---- |
| 2   | cccc | dddd |
| 3   | aaaa | eeee |
| 4   | ffff | bbbb |
```